# Problems with inferring types with bounded wildcards

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

What's the proper way of setting `temp2.in` in the below snippet? Why does the code not compile?

```
public class WildCards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheBox<Integer> temp1 = new TheBox<Integer>();
        temp1.set(10);
        TheBox<? extends Number> temp2 = temp1;
        temp2.set(1);
    }

    public static class TheBox<T> {
        T in;

        public T get() {
            return in;
        }

        public void set(T in) {
            this.in = in;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: `TheBox<? extends Number>` could be e.g. `TheBox<BigInteger>`. We can't be sure whether it is `TheBox<Integer>` and can accept `int` values or not.

Comment: Excellent answer to a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/683077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are only allowed to do with `temp2` things that are legal to do with `TheBox` parametrized by **any** possible subclass of `Number`.  That includes subclasses of `Number` that haven't even been written yet.  `Integer` can only be assigned to *some* subclasses of `Number` but not all.

The only legal argument to give to `temp2.set` is `null`.  That's because `null` can be assigned to anything.

Please clarify what you mean by "whats the proper way of setting temp2.in".  Proper in what way?  What is the desired behavior of this code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the methods I am allowed to use are Object's methods not the reference's. I would also like to know if there is a way to somehow set temp2.in to Interger.valueOf(1).